# How to get dynamic table in jQuery from xml

Tags: jquery, xml, dynamic, html-table

I have an XML file and want to create dynamically html tables from the XML file.
In the XML file is an "header" for each node in the "body".

The Node Text from "header" must be the first column as ROW Description, and the value from the "body" the second column. The golden goal is to put in the third column a CSS Class with an image depends on the value, i think i must write here for each value a function to get this right?

I have a Jquery Code, to get for each Node (body, header) the value, how can I put this together to get the example table output? I'm absolutely a newbie in Jscripting.

Example Output Table:

```
   <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <td width="33%" valign="top">Label</td>
            <td width="33%" valign="top">Value</td>
            <td width="33%" valign="top">Image</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="33%" valign="top">Name</td>
            <td width="33%" valign="top">C0</td>
            <td width="33%" valign="top"><img src=""></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="33%" valign="top">Computer Type</td>
            <td width="33%" valign="top">C1</td>
            <td width="33%" valign="top"><img src=""></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<systems name="client" xmlns="http://..." xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<header>
    <c0>
        <name>Name</name>
    </c0>
    <c1>
        <name>Computer type</name>
    </c1>
    <c2>
        <name>Number of CPUs</name>
    </c2>
    <c3>
        <name>Total RAM</name>
    </c3>
    <c4>
        <name>Hard disks</name>
    </c4>
    <c5>
        <name>Logical drives</name>
    </c5>
    <c6>
        <name>System drive free space</name>
    </c6>
    <c7>
        <name>System drive usage</name>
    </c7>
</header>
<body>
    <r>
        <c0>PC0001</c0>
        <c1>desktop</c1>
        <c2>1</c2>
        <c3>8589934592</c3>
        <c4>
            <disk>
                <manufacturer>Western Digital</manufacturer>
                <name>WDC WD5000AAKX-083CA0</name>
                <size>500105249280</size>
            </disk>
        </c4>
        <c5>
            <drive>
                <name>C</name>
                <sys>true</sys>
                <size>400000282624</size>
                <free>345680142336</free>
            </drive>
            <drive>
                <name>D</name>
                <sys>false</sys>
                <size>100000591872</size>
                <free>99903418368</free>
            </drive>
        </c5>
        <c6>345680142336</c6>
        <c7>13.6</c7>
    </r>
</body>
```

**UPDATE NEW JQUERY:**

```
                $(document).ready(function(){
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: 'clients.xml',
                    dataType: "xml",
                    success: function(xml) {
                        $(xml).find("systems").each(function () {
                            var LabelMetric = $(this).find('header').children().text();
                            $(this).find('body').children().each(function () {
                                var valueMetric = $(this).text();

                                $("#tablexml").last().append('<tr><td width="33%" valign="top">' + LabelMetric + '</td> + <td width="33%" valign="top">' + valueMetric + '</td></tr>');
                            });
                        });
                      }
                });
            });
```

Comment: `function JQuery(document) {` what is the purpose of it?

Comment: I have an $.ajax request which give me an XML File back with success: JQuery. I want to show the data on a local Website.

Comment: Have a look at http://www.w3schools.com/Dom/dom_examples.asp to see how to iterate over the XML and add it to the dom.  When you're getting the values you can add them to a string and then insert them with any number of jQuery methods.

Comment: I tried it bevor with Javascript and DOM  but i had problems to get all ChildNodes. I have now this sript, how can i loop through both nodes, the header and body to get each single text in a table row? See the new script on top of this question. Thanks!